# Problem in starting REST server using hyperledger composer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I have setup hyperledger fabric and also started network.But when I
create composer-rest-server and access it on my browser and access 
https://localhost:3000/explorer
I'm getting an error:

```
    Unhandled error for request GET /explorer: Error: Cannot GET /explorer
    at raiseUrlNotFoundError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-rest- 
   server/node_modules/loopback/server/middleware/url-not-found.js:21:17)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] 
    (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-rest- 
    server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-rest- 
    server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-rest- 
     server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-rest- 
    server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-rest- 
    server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-rest- 
    server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:635:15
    at next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-rest- 
    server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:260:14)
    at Function.handle (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-rest- 
    server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
    at router (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-rest- 
    server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] 
    (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-rest- 
    server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-rest- 
    server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-rest- 
    server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-rest- 
    server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-rest- 
    server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at urlencodedParser (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-rest- 
    server/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/urlencoded.js:91:7)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you start the server it asks certain question with you, one of them is 

`Specify if you want to enable the explorer test interface`

Make sure you put `yes` in it